# Document databases/Key-value stores for use with .Net projects

Tags: .net, database, nosql, keystore

Are there any document databases and/or key-value stores (something like Project Voldemort, MongoDB, etc.) that work well with .Net projects?  Most of the options I've looked at so far seem to be more geared towards the non-Microsoft/Java/open-source technologies and I was wondering if anyone had any experience/recommendations with such solutions for the Microsoft stack.

Comment: Persistence is a must.  Sorry, I didn't mention this before.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

CouchDB is well regarded and [accessible via .Net](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1050152/use-couchdb-with-net) albeit not that pleasant to install on windows still.

Thrift api compatible servers like [cassandra](http://wiki.apache.org/cassandra/) will talk [.Net](http://svn.apache.org/viewvc/incubator/thrift/trunk/lib/csharp/)

[Tokyo Cabinet](http://1978th.net/tokyocabinet/) can be simply accessed by the (apparently) full [.Net port of Tokyo Tyrant](http://tokyotyrant.codeplex.com/)

[MongoDB](http://www.mongodb.org) has [several .Net api options](http://www.mongodb.org/display/DOCS/Drivers)

I would suggest that indicating whether sharding (or other horizontal scaling capabilities) are more or less important that some level of consistency in your persistent store since all of the above trade off the consistency for low latency and good scalability in some way or another.

Answer (score 2):

there is a memcachedb which is persistent, and also the tokyo cabinet which is persistent (and supposedly very fast). Both are compatible with the memcache protocol sot you can use their drivers for .net

Answer (score 1):

The community based opensource.net driver for mongodb works quite nice and is really fast. It can be found on the mongodb homepage

Answer (score 1):

[Microsoft "Velocity"](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/data/cc655792.aspx) does this (also a link to [their blog](http://blogs.msdn.com/velocity/)), but is still in community technology preview (i.e. "beta").

Other projects, like memcached, have .NET APIs.

Comment: Sorry, I didn't mention before, but one of the requirements I'm looking for is persistence.  Looks like an interesting project nonetheless.

Answer (score 1):

Community supported C# driver for [mongodb](http://www.mongodb.org/display/DOCS/Drivers) avaiable in [github](http://github.com/samus/mongodb-csharp)

And another promising key value store is [hyphertable](http://www.hypertable.org/). You can access this through c# thrift client. You can get it [here](http://wiki.apache.org/thrift/ThriftUsageC%23).

I dont have any working experience with thrift clients. So you can clarify it in hyphertable forum..

Answer (score 0):

The link to Tokyo Cabinet for .Net is for the client driver.
There is a port of the Tokyo Cabinet og Tyrant it can be downloaded from this site:
http://spench.net/drupal/software/tokyocabinet

I have not testet this port.