# Fastest key-value pair database?

Tags: database, performance, key-value-store

I am looking for fastest free key-value pair database available. Database doesn't have to be server-based, it can be linked into the application. I am aware of [Tokyo Cabinet](http://1978th.net/tokyocabinet/). Any other suggestions?

Comment: Are you aware of any others, or are you expecting the answers to just list them all?

Comment: Just the *fastest*, not all :)

Comment: That *may* depend on your environment. Just pick some popular ones, run benchmarks on it and conclude (and share results with us here).

Answer (score 2):

i vote for BerkeleyDB!

Answer (score 1):

I don't know about fastest, but you can look at this question: [Document databases/Key-value stores for use with .Net projects](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1543965/document-key-value-stores-with-net-projects).

The reality, is that you will probably need to clearly establish a performance baseline and profile different databases for yourself to determine which will have acceptable performance for your specific application.

Answer (score 0):

An in-memory sql lite database