# .Net friendly, local, key-value pair, replicatable datastore

Tags: .net, vb.net, replication, datastore, key-value-store

I am looking for a key/value type datastore with very specific requirements. Anyone know anything that will work?

1. Needs to be a component of some sort. No additional installation needed.
2. The datastore needs to be on the local hard drive.
3. I am using VB.Net for a desktop app running Windows XP through 7 so it needs to callable by that environment.
4. It needs to replicatable. If I have four copies of my app running on the network, each local copy of the datastore needs to replicate with the others. As close to real time as possible.

The first three are easy, I can do that with ADO.Net out of the box. The last one, replication, is the one I do not have answer to.

Does such an animal exist?

Comment: I don't mean to be picky but "real-time" does not mean fast....it simply means a given operation will complete in a deterministic amount of time. You might ask yourself: "What is the maximum amount of time the system can allow for replication before the replication would be considered to have failed ?".

Comment: Good point to ponder on. Thanks.

Comment: Anyone used Berkeley DB? That seems to meet all requirements. And it's free for open source projects, which mine will be.

Answer (score 1):

perhaps have a look at http://ravendb.net/

in terms of replication  http://ravendb.net/documentation/replication

running locally as a service: http://ravendb.net/documentation/docs-deployment-service

Comment: Good to know about Raven for other projects, but I would prefer a component type of solution. Raven does look pretty easy to install, but it is yet another piece to control. I am currently using SQLite, but there is no decent replication solution available.

Comment: I'll add the that the pricing model might be a bit cost prohibitive for some though.

Comment: yes I agree, raven is too pricey.  Especially for an unestablished product.

Answer (score 1):

Key-value only then try RavenDbs' sibling , Rhino DHT. Or probably more accurate as it's grandparent. RhinoDHT is a key-value store, distributable (there is a non distributable version as well).

Component based as you require (I believe just a single DLL?)

Answer (score 0):

CouchDB might be one solution, [using a.NET wrapper](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1050152/use-couchdb-with-net). It might be a bit of a pain to integrate though, as it needs Apache.

Amazon SimpleDB is another option, combined with a simple `XmlSerialization` implementation of an `IDictionary`. It's free for less than 1gb of traffic per month, which is a lot of plain text.